# nextjs 13.5 link is refreshing page

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

```
import Link from "next/link";

import React from "react";

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul className="flex m-10 gap-10">
        <Link href="/">
          <li>Home</li>
        </Link>
        <Link href="/signin">
          <li>SignIn</li>
        </Link>
        <Link href="/signup">
          <li>SignUp</li>
        </Link>
        <Link href="/profile">
          <li>Profile</li>
        </Link>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navbar;

"use client";

import { sessionStatus } from "../utils/session";

import { redirect } from "next/navigation";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

const Page = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const session = sessionStatus;
    if (!session) {
      console.log("hello");
      redirect("/");
    } else {
      console.log("wow");
    }
  }, []);

  console.log("render");
  return <div>Profile page ddddd</div>;
};

export default Page;
import React from "react";

const Page = () => {
  return <div>SignIn page</div>;
};

export default Page;
```

so i have few doubts , as i am new to next
btw session storage is a variable only so need to call.
1.why the whole page is refreshing when i click on navbar links
2.why useeffect is not triggering in profile and route is not protected

Comment: what is this code? import { sessionStatus } from "../utils/session";

Comment: export const sessionStatus = false

Comment: Can you post a photo of your folder structure?

Answer (score 1):

```
      <ul className="flex m-10 gap-10">
        <Link href="/">
          <li>Home</li>
        </Link>
        <Link href="/signin">
          <li>SignIn</li>
        </Link>
        <Link href="/signup">
          <li>SignUp</li>
        </Link>
        <Link href="/profile">
          <li>Profile</li>
        </Link>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

This JSX structure is invalid, hence, causing a full reload. Instead change your code to the following:

```
<div>
      <ul className="flex m-10 gap-10">
        <li>
          <Link href="/">
            Home
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link href="/signin">
            SignIn
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link href="/signup">
            SignUp
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link href="/profile">
            Profile
          </Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please could you check the component name for the sign in page and also add the value to the dependency array like below.

````
  useEffect(() => {
    const session = sessionStatus;
    if (!session) {
      console.log("hello");
      redirect("/");
    } else {
      console.log("wow");
    }
  }, [sessionStatus]);```
````

Answer (score -1):

The Link component in Next.js is designed to handle client-side navigation without causing a full page reload. It uses JavaScript to intercept the click event and perform the navigation without making an actual HTTP request to the server.

To fix the issue, you should replace the `<li>` elements wrapped in `<Link>` components instead of using `<a>` tags directly. Here's an updated version of your code:

```
import Link from "next/link";
import React from "react";

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul className="flex m-10 gap-10">
        <li>
          <Link href="/">
            <a>Home</a>
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link href="/signin">
            <a>SignIn</a>
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link href="/signup">
            <a>SignUp</a>
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link href="/profile">
            <a>Profile</a>
          </Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

By wrapping the `<a>` tags inside the  components, Next.js will handle the navigation and prevent full page reloads when clicking on the links.